# Does education improve 'g'?

Tags: intelligence

It is, I believe, well known that education improves iq scores. Does it improve 'g'?

> the association of education with improved cognitive test scores is
> not mediated by g, but consists of direct effects on specific
> cognitive skills.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4445388/

This does, I assume, mean "no"? Is there any counter evidence or claims?